# How many geometric structures on manifolds are there?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, of dimension $n$. I know that there are many types of geometric structures on $M$. A large number of them are captured by the notion of a $G$-structure, which is a reduction of $M$'s frame bundle $F(M)$ to a Lie subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, the structure group of $F(M)$.

Kobayashi, in his text "Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry," is kind enough to provide a list of some $G$-structures. His list includes structures with which most people are acquainted, such as $O(n)$-structures (Riemannian metrics), $O(n)\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$-structures (conformal structures), and $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$-structures (volume forms). Several important ones are missing, such as almost CR-structures, which in the case $n=2k+1$ are reductions of $F(M)$ to the subgroup $G_0$ of $GL(2k+1,\mathbb{R})$ with elements
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & x\\
0 & y
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A\in GL(k,\mathbb{C})$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2k}$, and $y\in \mathbb{R}^\times$.

Questions: Is there a more comprehensive list of $G$-structures somewhere? Are there "exotic" $G$-structures that have appeared in the literature?

Comment: According to your definition, a list of $G$-structures is a list of subgroups of $GL(n)$. (In fact, one should also include at least various coverings of these subgroups, to accommodate for all sorts of $\mathrm{Spin}$-structures.) IMHO, a **very** exotic but popular structure is the $G_2$-structure on $7$-manifolds.

Comment: I agree. However I don't imagine that every possible structure group reduction has been studied, nor do I imagine that they all are worthy of study. If $M$ is a $4$-manifold, then I can reduce its frame bundle to, say, $SO(3)\times 1$, or $SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times SO(2)$. Has anyone looked at these $G$-structures?

Comment: Well, **some** reductions of $SO(2n+1)$ to $SO(2n)$ are called contact structures and are indeed studied a lot. Although I do agree that not everything is studied/worth studying, but this does not seem to be relevant to your question title :)

Comment: Also, I think that any reduction of $SO$ to a **subgroup** is basically a question about the holonomy group of the metric, and I think that such things **are** studied.

Comment: Although of course, torsion-freeness is required for the holonomy to be $G$. Note also that any distribution (in the sense of Frobenius) is a structure, and these are studied in many contexts.

Comment: You should probably make explicit what makes your question different from «what are the coverings of linear Lie groups?» which is what the comments are converging to.

Comment: @user41626:  On a compact $4$-manifold, you can reduce to an $\mathrm{SO}(3)\times 1$ structure if and only if $M$ is orientable and has vanishing Euler characteristic.  To reduce to $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\times\mathrm{SO}(2)$, you need to know that the manifold is orientable and possesses a continuous rank-$2$ subbundle $E\subset TM$ (and conversely).  For example, $S^4$ does not possess a $G$-structure of either kind.  In fact, the only connected $G\subset\mathrm{GL}(4,\mathbb{R})$ that work in this case must, up to conjugacy, contain an $\mathrm{SO}(4)$.

Comment: Geometric structures on 4-manifolds were classified some time ago.  It was a ?Cambridge? or perhaps ?Oxford? student that did not remain in mathematics.  Jon Hillman wrote up the results in his book "4-manifolds, geometries and knots" http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/hillman.pdf The upshot is geometric 4-manifolds are much like geometric 3-manifolds, in that they are "generalized Seifert fibre spaces over surfaces" with a few small exceptions, like hyperbolic manifolds.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Your comment assumes that the geometric structures are locally homogeneous. There is no classification of $G$-structures on 4-manifolds.

Comment: @Ben McKay: I did not realize people were interested in geometric structures that are not locally homogeneous.

Comment: @Ryan: I think the term "geometric structure" is a little misleading here. In particular I don't think the OP means a geometric structure in the sense of Thurston, but means e.g. an orientation or a spin structure.

Comment: The OP's question was about $G$-structures, not geometric structures. As, the OP states "A large number of [geometric structures] are captured by the notion of a $G$-structure", so the OP makes the distinction. Also, one should be careful; the 'classification' of geometric structures, à la Thurston's 8 geometries in dimension $3$, makes assumptions (such as, for example, that the geometric structure can be found on some compact manifold) that often are not made explicit in superficial expositions. Without these assumptions, there are far more than $8$ transitive pseudo-groups in dimension $3$.

Answer (score 8):

Any map whatsoever from a space $X$ to $BO(n)$ gives a notion of $X$-structure for $n$-manifolds given by a choice of lift (up to homotopy) of the classifying map $M \to BO(n)$ of the tangent bundle of such a manifold $M$ to $X$ (together with a choice of homotopy).

When $X$ is itself $BG$ for some Lie group $G$ and the map $BG \to BO(n)$ is induced by a map $G \to O(n)$ of Lie groups this reproduces a more classical flavor of structure, but this more general setting includes, for example, the case of [string structures](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+structure), where $X = BString(n)$ does not arise in the more classical way. This very general notion of structure on a manifold arises, for example, in Lurie's discussion of the cobordism hypothesis.

So one terrible answer to your question is: there is a notion of (tangential) structure on an $n$-manifold for every isomorphism class of $n$-dimensional vector bundle on some space.

Comment: This is fantastic and is what I was hoping my question would produce.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a comprehensive list and I'll mention some $G$ structures that seemingly were ignored.

A presimplectic structure on an even dimensional manifold $M$ is a $G$ structure, with  $G=Sp(2n,\mathbb{R}).$

An almost complex structure on a vector bundle of rank $2n$ is a $G$ structure with  $G= \bigg\{  \left( \begin{array}{ll} A & B \\ 
-B & A \end{array} \right) \,\ |\,\ A,B \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})  \bigg\}$

More exotic ones:

A nonvanising section $\sigma$ on a vector bundle $E \rightarrow M$  of rank $n$   can be viewd as  a $G$ structure with $ G= \bigg\{  \left( \begin{array}{ll} 1 & A \\ 
0 & B  \end{array} \right) \,\ |\,\ A \in M_{n-1,1}(\mathbb{R}) \,\ ,B \in M_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}) \bigg\}, $

A parralelization of a plane bundle(for simplicity!) can be viewed as a $G$ structure with

$G= \bigg\{  \left( \begin{array}{ll} a & b \\ 
b & a \end{array} \right) \,\ |\,\ a^2-b^2 \neq 0  \bigg\}$

Moreover, since the structure group $G$ acts by conjugations on $GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$, one can calculate the invariant polynomial functions in the entries of a matrix and see if one can obtain cohomology invariants for the $G$ structure. A concrete example is the pfaffian of a matrix asociated to an $SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ stucture that yields the Euler form of a connection.